# Why is pandas.read_sql with params so much slower than with inline params

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

I have cgi page in python that interacts with data in SQL Server using pandas.

**Summary**

A query is run based on user interaction with some other data from another query. These are both loaded using the `pandas.read_sql()` function. For some reason, the second query was running much slower than it should have been when comparing it in python to when it's directly run on the database (in SQL Server Management Studio). After some testing, I found out that the query is much slower when I pass the param using `params=[p]`, which I was doing initially and would prefer to do, rather than inline in the query (code below). I'm not sure why this is so and thought someone out there might have an idea.

**Code**

```
#Method 1: using param=[] 
query = "select * from FloorPlans where hydroid = ? order by plan_date desc"
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
df2 = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=[row["HydroID"]])
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print(t2-t1)

#Method 2: inline
query = "select * from FloorPlans where hydroid = '" + row["HydroID"] + "' order by plan_date desc"
t3 = datetime.datetime.now()
df2 = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
t4 = datetime.datetime.now()
print(t4-t3)
```

**Times**

Method 1: ~210.0 seconds

Method 2: ~0.05 seconds

In SSMS:  ~0.04 seconds

---

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I've checked to make sure the param method is sending a string as expected (by wrapping it in str()) and I've checked with a variety of values. I have a clustered index on the hydrioid column, but that shouldn't matter since it's the same value in all three cases. I also have two other queries doing pretty much the same thing (select * on varchar column with a clustered index) on other tables and they don't have this problem.

The only thing I have been able to think of so far is that in the FloorPlans table, hydrioid is always a sequence of numbers at the moment (this is likely to change in the future as other tables which contain the same identifier have instances with alphanumeric hydroids) and despite ensuring the variable is a string, something in pandas is converting it back to an int prior to sending to SQL, which causes issues with the query.

Comment: Is [hydroid] a `varchar` (as opposed to an `nvarchar`) column?

Comment: yes, [hydroid] is a varchar. Could this be causing an issue?

Comment: It might. Try re-running Method 2 with a Unicode literal, i.e., `... where hydroid = N'" + row["HydroID"] + ...` and check the execution time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Python_3 then all strings are Unicode. The Python code ...

```python
sql = "SELECT * FROM MillionRows WHERE varchar_column = ?"
crsr.execute(sql, 'record012345')
```

... gets processed on the SQL Server as

```sql
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(24)',N'SELECT * FROM MillionRows WHERE varchar_column = @P1',N'record012345'
select @p1
```

Notice that the parameter value is Unicode: `nvarchar(24)`

Now if we check the actual execution plan of the equivalent query in SSMS ...

```sql
SELECT * FROM MillionRows WHERE varchar_column = N'record012345'
```

... we see

```
   Physical operation: Index Scan
Actual Number of Rows: 1
  Number of Rows Read: 1000000
```

On the other hand, if we run a query that uses a `varchar` value ...

```sql
SELECT * FROM MillionRows WHERE varchar_column = 'record012345'
```

... the execution plan shows us

```
   Physical operation: Index Seek
Actual Number of Rows: 1
  Number of Rows Read: 1
```

The difference is due to the fact that the first query must do a Scan for the (implicitly converted) `nvarchar` value against the `varchar` index, while the second query is able to do a Seek instead of a Scan.

The fix for the raw Python code is to use [setinputsizes](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#setinputsizeslist_of_value_tuples) to specify that the query parameter should be a `varchar` ...

```python
sql = "SELECT * FROM MillionRows WHERE varchar_column = ?"
crsr.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_VARCHAR, 25)])
crsr.execute(sql, 'record012345')
```

.. which gets processed on the SQL Server as

```sql
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 varchar(25)',N'SELECT * FROM MillionRows WHERE varchar_column = @P1','record012345'
select @p1
```

A workaround for pandas `read_sql_query` is to `CAST` the parameter value in the SQL query itself

```python
sql = "SELECT * FROM MillionRows WHERE varchar_column = CAST(? AS varchar(25))"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, params=['record012345'])
```

Comment: This is interesting. I know you contribute to the [`pyodbc`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) project. Possibly handle the `setinputsizes` under the hood to use `varchar` for ascii characters and `nvarchar` for all else?